# Query to replace specific character in a table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have table that contain many fields. want i want is to make a single query that will update every field in my table which contain \' to \\\'. For one field the query is

> update table set column1 = replace(column1, '\'', '\\\'');

but what if i have to replace same thing in all the fields. do i have to write same query for every field ? is there any way to write one query that will update all the fields.

Comment: So you want _every_ field in _every_ table in the database to be updated?

Comment: yes i want every field in my table to be updated. say table name is table1

Answer (score 1):

**Q: Do I have to write same query for every field? Is there any way to write one query that will update all the fields?**

Each column you want to update will need to be referenced. You can update multiple columns in a single statement. (You don't have to run separate statements; it will be more efficient to update them in one fell swoop.

```
 UPDATE mytable 
    SET col1 = expr1
      , col2 = expr2 
      , col3 = expr3
```

But we do need to explicitly reference each column we want to update.

---

We can use a SQL statement to get the column names. Likely, we'll want to exclude integer/decimal/float columns, as well as ENUM, SET, DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, etc.  Here's an example of a query that gets the column names:

```
  SELECT c.column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
   WHERE c.table_schema = 'mydatabase'
     AND c.table_name   = 'mytable'
```

NOTE: The backslash character is an escape character in MySQL literals,

To represent backslash and single quote as a string literal

```
  '\\'''
```

To represent three backslashes and a single quote as a string literal

```
  '\\\\\\'''
```

If I wanted to replace occurrences of a single quote, with a literal backslash and a single quote, I'd use an expression like this:

```
  REPLACE(foo, '''', '\\''')
```

When I need to do something like this, to reference a bunch of columns, I'll use a query to help generate some expressions; something like this:

```
  SELECT CONCAT(',`',c.column_name,'` = REPLACE(`',c.column_name
            ,'`,'''''''',''\\\\'''''')') AS expr
    FROM information_schema.columns c
   WHERE c.table_schema = 'mydatabase'
     AND c.table_name   = 'mytable'
     AND c.data_type IN ('char','varchar')
```

Then I can take the values returned for `expr` and use that in a subsequent statement.  Also be aware of increasing the number of characters in the column, that this doesn't exceed the maximum size.

Comment: This still doesn't avoid the problem of manually doing an `UPDATE` of each column.

Comment: i want to replace ' with \' actually . tell what should be written in query then for replacing ' with \'

Comment: @mbr: I typically escape a single quote with another single quote. e.g.  **`'he''s here'`**.  That works in a lot of databases; MySQL, also let's you use the backslash to escape it, so what you have should work. I'd use an expression in the SELECT list of a query against information_schema.columns to help me generate part of the statement I need to run.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: It's not really a problem. It's somewhat inconvenient, but not a problem. The identifiers must be referenced in the SQL statement. That's because of the way the SQL is parsed, and the statement is prepared. The columns to be updated can't be varied dynamically when the statement is submitted. The columns have to be explicitly referenced. The approach to making this dynamic is to do it in two steps: the first step is to run a SQL statement that gets a list of column names, and we use that to generate the statement we want to run.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this.

```
UPDATE table1, table2, ... 
SET column1 = expression1,
    column2 = expression2,
    ...
WHERE table1.column = table2.column
AND conditions;
```

If you’re updating two tables with identical data, there’s probably a better way to design your database. Remember to keep your programming DRY

**EDIT**: [*From OA's comments below*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398149/query-to-replace-specific-character-in-a-table/31398229#comment50771927_31398229):

```
DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
        SELECT column_name 
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
         WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name' 
         ORDER BY ordinal_position;

select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows; 
SET i = 1; 
the_loop: LOOP 
    IF i > num_rows THEN 
        CLOSE col_names; 
        LEAVE the_loop; 
    END IF; 
    FETCH col_names INTO col_name; //do whatever else you need to do with the col name 
    SET i = i + 1; 
END LOOP the_loop;
```

Comment: The OP wants to iterate over all columns in a single table, without having to list out each column manually.

Comment: DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
  SELECT column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
  ORDER BY ordinal_position;


select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;

SET i = 1;
the_loop: LOOP

   IF i > num_rows THEN
        CLOSE col_names;
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;


    FETCH col_names 
    INTO col_name;     

     //do whatever else you need to do with the col name

    SET i = i + 1;  
END LOOP the_loop;

Answer (score 0):

**That's the wrong approach.**  The data in the database should be un-escaped.  That is, you should have `'`, not `\'` or `\\\'`.  You application should expect to retrieve `'` and add escapes when necessary for whatever is happening next.

If you are using PHP, then use

- `urlencode()` for creating urls
- `htmlentities()` for escaping these 4 things that cause trouble in HTML:  `"&<>`
- `nl2br()` for making NL or CR act like `<br>`

`\'` is needed when *INSERTing* apostrophes into tables; see mysqli_real_escape_string().